# webpack callback when file is changed : Callback NOT static configuration

Tags: node.js, callback, webpack, watch

I configured webpack to watch the `./src` directory , and it works fine ; any file belongs to `./src` directory & when it is changed & saved , webpack refreshes the bundled files.

```
const conf = {
      //....
       plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
       ]
      //...
}
```

I am looking now for a something like the following :

```
const conf = {
      //....
       plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
       ],
      onWatchedChange: function(filePath) { //  LOOKING for this 

        if(filePath.endsWith('.js'))
           // run command line or do any thing
      }
}
```

Assuming that I am looking a NodeJS solution in general, I am aware that  a solution can be :

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('./src', {encoding: 'buffer'}, (eventType, filename) => {
  if (filename)
    console.log(filename);
    // Prints: <Buffer ...>
});
```

How to integrate the last snippet within `webpack-dev-server` configuration ?

OR

Does webpack supports a callback similar to the proof of concept that I explained (`onWatchedChange` callback) ?

Comment: Just -ing for the language, which use  characters.